# Loading XML document from a url issue

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

my code :

```
XmlDocument xml1 = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument xml2 = new XmlDocument();
        xml1.Load("http://www.oztivo.net/xmltv/FMDRA_2013-05-31.xml.gz");
        xml2.Load("http://www.oztivo.net/xmltv/GEM-ACT_2013-05-16.xml.gz");
```

my problem is that on page load for first time everything work great but on the refresh it's giving me an error :

```
'', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
```

Do anyone know how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Your URL is for a gzipped version file. You'd need to decompress that first... or remove the `.gz` part from the URL.

Comment: and how should i decompress it ?

Comment: @samer like this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/decompress

Comment: i want to set url and return xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx) and the [`AutomaticDecompression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression.aspx) property to automatically decompress the 'gziped' file:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.oztivo.net/xmltv/FMDRA_2013-05-31.xml.gz");
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

XmlDocument xml1 = new XmlDocument();
xml1.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

**[Update]** Note :

In fact, when testing your urls we can see that they are 'gziped'. If you try to access the urls from a web browser you will see the XML content displayed because the web browser decompress the content.

**[Update2]**
`CreateHttp` is available from .NET 4 or later. You can do `(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create` instead if working with .NET < .NET 4

Comment: it giving me an error on CreateHttp as the function do not exist

Comment: `CreateHttp` is available from .NET 4 or later. You can do `(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create` instead.